# React app with styled components and twin.macro set global styles

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css

I am using create-react-app, styled components and twin.macro to apply tailwind classes to my React elements. This is working well.

I have a small subset of rules that I cannot be applied because either

- The element they should be applied to is outside of the react app scope (body, #root)
- The styles should be applied globally instead of to a specific element.

Here is what I want to be my global stylesheet.

```
    body {
      @apply bg-gray-100 select-none;
    }
    
    #root {
      @apply h-screen text-sm;
    }
    
    input:focus,
    select:focus,
    textarea:focus,
    button:focus,
    div[contenteditable]:focus {
      @apply outline-none
    }
```

Does twin.macro provide the functionality to do add global styles? If not what is my best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the global styles that your chosen css-in-js package provides:

- [Emotion's `global`](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals#gatsby-focus-wrapper)
- [Styled Components `createglobalstyle`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)
- [Goobers `glob`](https://github.com/cristianbote/goober#glob)

Thanks for using twin :)

Comment: Thanks for creating Twin! It's a massive timesaver when it comes to writing CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Does twin.macro provide the functionality to do add global styles?
the answer YES

twin.macro use of global style from styled-component/@emotion, (but by default it uses @emotion). but don't worry, you can change it using styled-component

Have you followed these steps?

https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/blob/master/docs/styled-components/create-react-app.md